# tbb increment number of vector element without using mutex

Tags: c++, image-processing, tbb

Currently I am working on paralizing an image processing algorithm to extract edges from a given image. I recently started with code parallelizing.

Anyway a part of the program requires me to compute the histogram of the image and count the number of occurding pixels from 1 to its maximum gradient Intensity.

I have implemented it as the following:

```
tbb::concurrent_vector<double> histogram(32768);

tbb::parallel_for(tbb::blocked_range<size_t>(1, width - 1),
    [&](const tbb::blocked_range<size_t>& r)
{
    unsigned int idx;
    for (size_t w = r.begin(); w != r.end(); ++w) //1 to (width -1)
    {
        for (size_t h = 1; h < height - 1; ++h)
        {
            idx = h * width + w;

            //DO SOME STUFF BEFORE

            //Get max gradient intensity
            if (pgImg[idx] > maxGradIntensity)
            {
                maxGradIntensity = pgImg[idx];
            }
            //Get histogram information
            if (pgImg[idx] > 0)
            {
                tbb::mutex::scoped_lock sync(locked);
                ++histogram[(int)pgImg[idx]];
                ++totalGradPixels;
            }
        }
    }
});
histogram.resize(maxGradIntensity);
```

So the part where it becomes tricky for me is the following:

```
if (pgImg[idx] > 0)
{
    tbb::mutex::scoped_lock sync(locked);
    ++histogram[(int)pgImg[idx]];
    ++totalGradPixels;
}
```

How can I avoid using `tbb::mutex`? I had no luck with setting the vector to `tbb::atomic`. Maybe I did something wrong there. Any help on this topic would be appreciated.

Comment: Make the histogram data local to each thread and then sum them when all the threads complete.  So if you had 10 threads you would have 10 sets of histogram data which you would sum when the 10 threads all finish.  No need for any locks.

Comment: Sounds good to me. Could you may provide an example?

Comment: I don't see why it cannot be atomic, try `int` instead of double for starters. Also, you don't need `concurrent_vector` here since you don't need it to grow concurrently.

Comment: another hint is to use `blocked_range2d` for additional cache efficiency.

Comment: Agree with the recommendation of Richard Critten, with an additional point  to use tbb::combinable or tbb::enumerable_thread_specific for thread-local histogram accumulators. The benefit of those is that local copies are created dynamically on demand (so you do not need to know the number of threads in advance) and that there is a method to combine the local copies.

Comment: Thank you very much thats a first hint to start with :)

Comment: Thank you Richard Citten and also Alexey Kuvanov for your advises. I have manged to implement it. Unfortunatly i can't upvote your suggestions. For people having a similar issue I highly recommand having a look at this: https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/thread_local_storage/enumerable_thread_specific_cls.html